# tkinter ListBox and Label position

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I am little bit comfused with grid system in tkinter Python. Can anyone show how to make it in right way?! ListBox and Label items positions are not in the places where I expexted to see them.

CODE:

```
        self.third_label = Label(self, text="TEXT")
        self.third_label.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
        self.fourth_label = Label(self, text="LONG TEXT")
        self.fourth_label.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
        self.fifth_label = Label(self, text="SOME TEXT")
        self.fifth_label.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=6, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
        self.sixth_label = Label(self, text="BIG TEXT")
        self.sixth_label.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
        self.first_listbox = Listbox(self, width=40, selectmode=EXTENDED)
        self.first_listbox.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
        self.second_listbox = Listbox(self, width=40, selectmode=EXTENDED)
        self.second_listbox.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
        self.third_listbox = Listbox(self, width=40, selectmode=EXTENDED)
        self.third_listbox.grid(row=3, column=4, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
        self.fourth_listbox = Listbox(self, width=40, selectmode=EXTENDED)
        self.fourth_listbox.grid(row=3, column=6, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
```

What I have right now:
[image]

Just Example:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grid system works fine. The problem is your columnspans, which don't make much sense. You're gridding the widgets into certain column positions then giving them a columnspan that is beyond the range of where the next widget is to be gridded so on and so forth.

Small example:

```
import string
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

for i in range(3):
    tk.Label(root, text=string.ascii_letters).grid(row=0, column=i)
    tk.Listbox(root, width=40).grid(row=1, column=i)

root.mainloop()
```

Edit from comments (for listbox size):

To get the number of lines in a listbox you can use the `.size()` method.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I understand my mistake! By the way can I ask one more question? How in Python I can know Count of ListBox. Lets say I have such `if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)` code in C# Is it same with this: `if self.first_listbox is None:`